# How to refer to a folder within the "public" static folder from an router file?

Tags: node.js, express, path, public, multer

I am trying to refer to a folder called `tracks_folder` within my `public` folder from a router.

The simplified structure of my project is the following

```
app.js
routes/ 
      tracks/
            router.js
public/
      tracks_folder/
```

Basically I want to refer from `router.js` to `tracks_folder`, in order to upload a file to that folder, but I am not managing to do it.

I have tried with:

1. `../../public/tracks_folder/`
2. `../../tracks_folder/`
3. `./tracks_folder/`

But none of them work. In my `app.js` I have

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

but for example for the third case I receive the following error:

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'tracks_folder/aaa.mp3'
```

at Error (native)

Theoretically I should be able to refer to the `tracks_folder` folder using at least the first method, but it does work.

I am using multer to upload files and its disk storage to store them...

The following is the simplified problem-related code inside `router.js`:

```
...
var multer = require('multer')
var uploadFolder = "./tracks_folder/";

function formatTrackName(originalName) {
  return originalName.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase();
}

var trackStorage = multer.diskStorage({
  // used to determine within which folder the uploaded files should be stored.
  destination: function(req, file, callback) {

    callback(null, uploadFolder);
  },

  filename: function(req, res, callback) {
    // req.body.name should contain the name of track
    callback(null, formatTrackName(req.body.name) + ".mp3");
  }
});


var upload = multer({
  storage: trackStorage
})

...
...
```

And this is my unimplemented post method:

```
router.post('/upload', upload.single("track"), function(req, res) {

});
```

Comment: You should probably include the code where you are trying to write the file.

Comment: @mscdex I edited my question with the requested details. By the way, this disk storage mechanism really handles the whole process of storing the file, or just stores the files temporarily (and I should then handle the write of the file using e.g. `fs`'s functions)? Honestly it is not clear at all from the documentation...

Answer (score 0):

try **./public/tracks_folder**

It worked for me